# Django-Private-Chat in , TemplateDoesNotExist at /dialogs/

Tags: python, django, django-models

[image]

This is the code of my `base.html`

{% comment %}
As the developer of this package, don't place anything here if you can help it
since this allows developers to have interoperability between your template
structure and their own.

Example: Developer melding the 2SoD pattern to fit inside with another pattern::

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<!-- Their site uses old school block layout -->
{% block extra_js %}

    <!-- Your package using 2SoD block layout -->
    {% block javascript %}
        <script src="{% static 'js/ninja.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endblock javascript %}

{% endblock extra_js %}{% endcomment %}
```

This is code of dialogs.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block css %}
{{ block.super }}
    <link href="{% static 'django_private_chat/css/django_private_chat.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
{% endblock css %}
{% block content %}
<input id="owner_username" type="hidden" value="{{ request.user.username }}">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="user-list-div">
            <ul>
{% for dialog in object_list %}
                    <li>
                        {% if dialog.owner == request.user %}
                            {% with dialog.opponent.username as username %}
                                <a href="{% url 'dialogs_detail' username %}" id="user-{{ username }}"
                                   class="btn btn-danger">{% trans "Chat with" %} {{ username }}</a>
                            {% endwith %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% with dialog.owner.username as username %}
                                <a href="{% url 'dialogs_detail' username %}" id="user-{{ username }}"
                                   class="btn btn-danger">{% trans "Chat with" %} {{ username }}</a>
                            {% endwith %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                <span class="pull-right" hidden id="typing-text">
                    <strong>{{ opponent_username }} {% trans "is typing..." %}</strong>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p>
                {{ opponent_username }}
            </p>
            <p class="text-success" id="online-status" style="display: none">{% trans "Online" %}</p>
            <p class="text-danger" id="offline-status" style="display: none">{% trans "Offline" %}</p>

            <div class="messages-container">
                <div id="messages" class="messages">
                    {% for msg in active_dialog.messages.all %}
                        <div class="row {% if msg.read %}msg-read{% else %}msg-unread{% endif %}"
                             data-id="{{ msg.id }}">
                            <p class="{% if msg.sender == request.user %}pull-left{% else %}pull-right{% endif %}">
                                <span class="username">{{ msg.sender.username }}:</span>
                                {{ msg.text }}
                                <span class="timestamp">&ndash; <span
                                        data-livestamp="{{ msg.get_formatted_create_datetime }}">{{ msg.get_formatted_create_datetime }}</span></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="add-message">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="chat-message" class="form-control message"
                              placeholder="{% trans 'Write a message' %}"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                    <input id="btn-send-message" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right send-message"
                           style="margin-left: 10px;" value="{% trans 'Send' %}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_js %}
 {{ block.super }}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollmonitor/1.2.0/scrollMonitor.js"
        integrity="sha256-BseZlDlA+yL4qu+Voi82iFa5aaifralQEXIjOjaXgeo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var base_ws_server_path = "{{ ws_server_path }}";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var websocket = null;
        var monitor = null;

        function initReadMessageHandler(containerMonitor, elem) {
            var id = $(elem).data('id');
            var elementWatcher = containerMonitor.create(elem);
            elementWatcher.enterViewport(function () {
                var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                var packet = JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'read_message',
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                    username: opponent_username,
                    message_id: id
                });
                $(elem).removeClass('msg-unread').addClass('msg-read');
                websocket.send(packet);
            });
        }
function initScrollMonitor() {
            var containerElement = $("#messages");
            var containerMonitor = scrollMonitor.createContainer(containerElement);
            $('.msg-unread').each(function (i, elem) {
                if ($(elem).hasClass('opponent')){
                    initReadMessageHandler(containerMonitor, elem);
                }

            });
            return containerMonitor
        }
 function getOpponnentUsername() {
            return "{{ opponent_username }}";
        }

        // TODO: Use for adding new dialog
        function addNewUser(packet) {
            $('#user-list').html('');
            packet.value.forEach(function (userInfo) {
                if (userInfo.username == getUsername()) return;
                var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#user-list-item-template').html());
                $('#user-list').append(tmpl(userInfo))
            });
        }
function addNewMessage(packet) {
            var msg_class = "";
            if (packet['sender_name'] == $("#owner_username").val()) {
                msg_class = "pull-left";
            } else {
                msg_class = "pull-right";
            }
            var msgElem =
                $('<div class="row msg-unread" data-id="' + packet.message_id + '">' +
                    '<p class="' + msg_class + '">' +
                    '<span class="username">' + packet['sender_name'] + ': </span>' +
                    packet['message'] +
                    ' <span class="timestamp">&ndash; <span data-livestamp="' + packet['created'] + '"> ' + packet['created'] + '</span></span> ' +
                    '</p> ' +
                    '</div>');
            $('#messages').append(msgElem);
            scrollToLastMessage()
        }
 function scrollToLastMessage() {
            var $msgs = $('#messages');
            $msgs.animate({"scrollTop": $msgs.prop('scrollHeight')})
        }

        function generateMessage(context) {
            var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#chat-message-template').html());
            return tmpl({msg: context})
        }

        function setUserOnlineOffline(username, online) {
            var elem = $("#user-" + username);
            if (online) {
                elem.attr("class", "btn btn-success");
            } else {
                elem.attr("class", "btn btn-danger");
            }
        }

        function gone_online() {
            $("#offline-status").hide();
            $("#online-status").show();
        }

        function gone_offline() {
            $("#online-status").hide();
            $("#offline-status").show();
        }

        function flash_user_button(username) {
            var btn = $("#user-" + username);
            btn.fadeTo(700, 0.1, function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(800, 1.0);
            });
        }
function setupChatWebSocket() {
            var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
            websocket = new WebSocket(base_ws_server_path + '{{ request.session.session_key }}/' + opponent_username);

            websocket.onopen = function (event) {
                var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();

                var onOnlineCheckPacket = JSON.stringify({
                    type: "check-online",
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                    username: opponent_username

                });
                var onConnectPacket = JSON.stringify({
                    type: "online",
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}'

                });
 console.log('connected, sending:', onConnectPacket);
                websocket.send(onConnectPacket);
                console.log('checking online opponents with:', onOnlineCheckPacket);
                websocket.send(onOnlineCheckPacket);
                monitor = initScrollMonitor();
            };


            window.onbeforeunload = function () {

                var onClosePacket = JSON.stringify({
                    type: "offline",
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                    username: opponent_username,

                });
                console.log('unloading, sending:', onClosePacket);
                websocket.send(onClosePacket);
                websocket.close();
            };


            websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                var packet;

                try {
                    packet = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    console.log(packet)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }

                switch (packet.type) {
                    case "new-dialog":
                        // TODO: add new dialog to dialog_list
                        break;
                    case "user-not-found":
                        // TODO: dispay some kind of an error that the user is not found
                        break;
                    case "gone-online":
                        if (packet.usernames.indexOf(opponent_username) != -1) {
                            gone_online();
                        } else {
                            gone_offline();
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < packet.usernames.length; ++i) {
                            setUserOnlineOffline(packet.usernames[i], true);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "gone-offline":
                        if (packet.username == opponent_username) {
                            gone_offline();
                        }
                        setUserOnlineOffline(packet.username, false);
                        break;
                    case "new-message":
                        if (packet['sender_name'] == opponent_username || packet['sender_name'] == $("#owner_username").val()) {
                            addNewMessage(packet);
                            if (packet['sender_name'] == opponent_username) {
                                initReadMessageHandler(monitor, $("div[data-id='" + packet['message_id'] + "']"));
                            }
                        } else {
                            flash_user_button(packet['sender_name']);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "opponent-typing":
                        var typing_elem = $('#typing-text');
                        if (!typing_elem.is(":visible")) {
                            typing_elem.fadeIn(500);
                        } else {
                            typing_elem.stop(true);
                            typing_elem.fadeIn(0);
                        }
                        typing_elem.fadeOut(3000);
                        break;
                    case "opponent-read-message":
                        if (packet['username'] == opponent_username) {
                            $("div[data-id='" + packet['message_id'] + "']").removeClass('msg-unread').addClass('msg-read');
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.log('error: ', event)
                }
            }
        }

        function sendMessage(message) {
            var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
            var newMessagePacket = JSON.stringify({
                type: 'new-message',
                session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                username: opponent_username,
                message: message
            });
            websocket.send(newMessagePacket)
        }

        $('#chat-message').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13 && this.value) {
                sendMessage(this.value);
                this.value = "";
                return false
            } else {
                var opponent_username = getOpponnentUsername();
                var packet = JSON.stringify({
                    type: 'is-typing',
                    session_key: '{{ request.session.session_key }}',
                    username: opponent_username,
                    typing: true
                });
                websocket.send(packet);
            }
        });
 $('#btn-send-message').click(function (e) {
            var $chatInput = $('#chat-message');
            var msg = $chatInput.val();
            if (!msg) return;
            sendMessage($chatInput.val());
            $chatInput.val('')
        });

        setupChatWebSocket();
        scrollToLastMessage();
    });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The error (which btw you should include directly in your post, not as a link or image) clearly says that Django can't find your `base.html`. So please show us where it is in your file structure, and what the `TEMPLATES` setting is in `settings.py`

Comment: You don't have a base.html file how it will be extended. Create base.html first.

Comment: I already create base.html

Comment: base.html is on : myapp/templates/base.html

Answer (score 0):

You should copy both 'dialogs.html' and 'base.html' from:

```
\your_virtualenvs\your_project\Lib\site-packages\django_private_chat\templates\django_private_chat\
```

into:

```
\your_project\templates\django_private_chat\
```

in order to modify them accordingly.

And add this to your settings if you din't already:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       ...
       'DIRS': [ os.path.join( BASE_DIR, 'templates' ) ],
       ...
    }
]
```

Reference:

https://django-private-chat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#example-project